# ->% 192.168.2.0 overlaps with FastEthernet0 / 0

Tags: cisco

[image]

I am working within the Cisco Packet Tracer platform. I made all the necessary configurations but when assigning an IP address to my router, I get the  error message in title and I do not know how to fix it. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Although Mark did a good job filling in the missing blanks, your question seriously lacks details on the setup and where and when you see that error message.

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing my best to interpret that diagram, but I'm not exactly sure what the diagram is showing due to the labels being in inconsistent places. However:

It looks like on `Router10` you have `192.168.2.1/30` assigned to `Se0/0/0`. That subnet consumes the IP addresses `192.168.2.0 - 192.168.2.3`

You also looks like you have `192.168.2.1` in your diagram assigned to `Fa0/0`. No subnet is mentioned, but if I assume that's a `/24` then you've assigned `192.168.2.0 - 192.168.2.255` to `Fa0/0` as well.

So the router is correct, you have an overlapping IP configuration on two distinct interfaces on the same device, which is an invalid configuration.

Change your `192.168.2.1/30` link between `Router10` and `Router8` (I think? Router name is obscured) to a different subnet.